# Native Query for strict_word_similarity is not working

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, nativequery

I am trying to use strict_word_similarity of PostgreSQL to find difference between two words in java spring boot thru native query but it is giving me below error. I am unable to solve the error.

```
  @Query(
      nativeQuery = true,
      value =
              "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;"
              + "select cast(c.customer_master_id as varchar) as customer_master_id "
              + "from customer_account_service.customer c where c.dob=:dob and "
              + "c.gender=:gender and "
              + "(strict_word_similarity(CAST(:fullName AS text),  CAST(c.full_name AS text)) < :matchPercent or strict_word_similarity(REPLACE( CAST(c.full_name AS text),' ','') ,REPLACE(CAST(:fullName AS text),' ','')) = 1)")
  Set<String> searchCustomerEntitiesByNameDobAndGender(
      @Param("fullName") String fullName,
      @Param("dob") Timestamp dob,
      @Param("gender") String gender,
      @Param("matchPercent") Integer matchPercent);
```

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function strict_word_similarity(text, text) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Fortunately i was able to use levenshtein function similarly but not able to use strict_word_similarity

```
@Query(
      nativeQuery = true,
      value =
          "select cast(c.customer_master_id as varchar) as customer_master_id "
              + "from customer_account_service.customer c where c.dob=:dob and "
              + "((levenshtein(:fullName, c.full_name) * 100) / greatest(:nameLength, length(c.full_name))) < :matchPercent")
  Set<String> searchCustomerEntitiesByNameAndDob(
      @Param("fullName") String fullName,
      @Param("dob") Timestamp dob,
      @Param("nameLength") Integer nameLength,
      @Param("matchPercent") Integer matchPercent);
```

Comment: Is this query executed correctly on the database console?

Comment: If the extension already exists but with a schema not in your search path, then it won't be created again, but the functions it defines won't be findable.

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani Yes the query is working fine on database console.

Comment: @jjanes If have tried to use it with the schema ..then also it didn't work :- error
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function customer_account_service.strict_word_similarity(text, text) does not exist

Comment: if your query executed correctly on the database console, you can test it with org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate first , this should be like your console. this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate) should be helpful.